# Bash script that creates a local environment for CHICKEN scheme (like virtualenv for Python)

Tags: bash, scheme, installer

**Usage**

- To create a localenv called sicp, do `$ localenv sicp`
- Activate the localenv: `$ . sicp/bin/activate`
- Check installed eggs in the local repository: `$ chicken-status`
- Install a new egg called 'sicp' in the local repository: `$ chicken-install sicp`
- Deactivate the localenv: `$ deactivate`

This is the first time I have used bash for any purpose at all. Is there any other way to get the grandparent directory of the current directory?

```
#!/bin/bash 

if [ -z "${1}" ]; then
    echo 'Usage: localenv DIR'
    echo
    echo 'localenv: You must provide the name of the directory to install the chicken environment.'
    exit 1
elif [ -e "$(pwd)/${1}" ]; then
    echo 'localenv: file or directory already exists.'
    exit 1
fi

# check if chicken is installed and save the location of csi and chicken-install.
CSI=$(command -v csi)

if [ -z "${CSI}" ]; then
    echo 'CHICKEN is not installed!'
    exit 1
else
    echo "CHICKEN interpreter is at ${CSI}"
fi

CHICKEN_INSTALL=$(command -v chicken-install)

# obtain global CHICKEN_HOME, CHICKEN_PREFIX, CHICKEN_REPOSITORY paths
CHICKEN_HOME=$(${CSI} -p "(chicken-home)")
CHICKEN_PREFIX="$(dirname $(dirname ${CHICKEN_HOME}))"
CHICKEN_REPOSITORY=$(${CSI} -p "(repository-path)")
# chicken binary version
BINARY_VERSION=$(basename "${CHICKEN_REPOSITORY}")

# local copy of chicken files are kept here
LOCAL_CHICKEN_PREFIX=$(realpath "${1}")

# remember where we were before jumping directories
OLDPWD=$(pwd)

# create all the necessary directories
mkdir -p "${LOCAL_CHICKEN_PREFIX}" && cd "$_" || exit 1
mkdir -p bin lib/chicken share/chicken include/chicken

# populate ./bin
for file in ${CHICKEN_PREFIX}/bin/{chicken,chicken-bug,chicken-install,chicken-profile,chicken-status,chicken-uninstall,csi,csc,feathers}; do
    [ -f "${file}" ] && cp "${file}" ./bin
done

# initialize empty alternative repository
${CHICKEN_INSTALL} -init "./lib/chicken/${BINARY_VERSION}"

# include files are essential
cp -R "${CHICKEN_PREFIX}"/include/chicken/{chicken.h,chicken-config.h} ./include/chicken

# populate ./share
cp -R "${CHICKEN_HOME}/setup.defaults" ./share/chicken

# create init file for the localenv
# init file acts like .csirc for the localenv
touch "${LOCAL_CHICKEN_PREFIX}/.init"

# write activate file
# Backslash escapes '$' and prevents expansion of the shell variables
cat << EOF > "${LOCAL_CHICKEN_PREFIX}/bin/activate"
export OLDPATH="\${PATH}"
export PATH="${LOCAL_CHICKEN_PREFIX}/bin:\${PATH}"

export OLDPS1="\${PS1}"
export PS1="($1)\${PS1}"

export CHICKEN_PREFIX="${LOCAL_CHICKEN_PREFIX}"
export CHICKEN_HOME="${LOCAL_CHICKEN_PREFIX}/share/chicken"
export CHICKEN_REPOSITORY="${LOCAL_CHICKEN_PREFIX}/lib/chicken/${BINARY_VERSION}"
export LOCAL_CSIRC="${LOCAL_CHICKEN_PREFIX}/.init"

# register a feature identifier 'localenv'
# this is required to override commands in the .csirc file
alias csi="csi -D localenv"

# deactivation function
deactivate()
{
    export PATH="\${OLDPATH}"
    export PS1="\${OLDPS1}"
    unset OLDPATH
    unset OLDPS1
    unset CHICKEN_PREFIX
    unset CHICKEN_HOME
    unset CHICKEN_REPOSITORY
    unset LOCAL_CSIRC
    unalias csi
    unset -f deactivate
}

EOF

cd "${OLDPWD}"
```

Comment: Another way would be `"${CHICKEN_HOME}/../.."`, which is valid even if `$CHICKEN_HOME` is root. I prefer your current "double dirname" though.

Comment: Isn't code you haven't gotten working off-topic here?  This is also a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270624/get-grandparent-directory-in-bash-script-rename-files-for-a-directory-in-their

Comment: @chicks I have got it working. I was asking that particular question to make it more refined.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why the `$(pwd)/` prefix is needed in this condition:

> ```
> elif [ -e "$(pwd)/${1}" ]; then
> ```

If `${1}` is an absolute path, the condition may not match the directory, even if it exists. Why not write simply `[ -e "${1}" ]`, which should work well with both relative and absolute paths.

---

`OLDPWD` is automatically set by Bash when you change directories,
no need to set it manually.
In any case, since the script is intended to be *executed* instead of *sourced*,
there's no need to `cd` back to `$OLDPWD`.

---

As for `$(dirname $(dirname ${CHICKEN_HOME}))`, I think that's nicely readable. For the record, you could use `${CHICKEN_HOME%/*}` twice to strip suffixes until the grandparent (+ an extra check for the special case of `/`). Since parameter expansion is a built-in, this would be faster than executing `dirname` twice. The performance would make a difference if you called `dirname` a thousand times in a loop, but that's not the case here. And since using `dirname` is simpler and more readable, I would stick with that.